# Proof that a Octahedron graph is 3-colorable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing, planar-graphs

I worked on a problem that gives an adjacency matrix and lets you draw a graph from that. After some time I found that the graph is a) planar and b) not any planar graph, but a Octahedron.

[image]

The next part asked for a coloring of the graph and a proof thereof. We know that every planar graph can be colored in at most 4 colors by the 4-Color-Theorem, but after some trying I found out the above graph can be actually colored in 3 colors. Is there any straightforward proof of that, besides a proof by picture that just shows the actual coloring?

It has to do with the triangles that exist in the graph, so I thought a bit about using some kind of structural induction that starts with one triangle and then adds more until the structure is complete, but I think that is also quite involved.

Comment: There's only 6 vertices to colour, why not use a direct proof by construction?

Comment: That works, but isn't the OP looking for an intuition as to why it *should* be 3-colorable?

Comment: Well... It's a bipyramid on an even-sided polygon. So the polygon (here, square) can be two-coloured, with the two pyramid points in the third colour.

Comment: @KennyLau Can you give me a general idea of how that would work? You start with one vertex and add one edge after another? I would be interested in this, because there are really only very few vertices.

Answer (score 5):

Each vertex is adjacent to four others, and antipodal to one. There are six vertices, hence three nonadjacent, antipodal pairs. Each antipodal pair receives one color.

Answer (score 4):

If you know that the regular octahedron is the [dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_polyhedron) of the cube, then you know that $3$-coloring the *vertices* of the octahedron is equivalent to $3$-coloring the *faces* of the cube. If the cube is in standard position in a coordinate system, then each face of the cube is parallel to one of the three coordinate planes, and of course parallel faces can be given the same color.